# AmazonMQ Limited to 5 Consumers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-mq

I am using AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ) as an ESM for a lambda. I have no concurrency limit on the lambda itself, but the AmazonMQ ESM is limiting the concurrency to 5, and messages in queue aren't getting processed because it is waiting for 1 of the 5 lambdas to finish execution.

[image]

I want much higher concurrency, into the thousands. How can I tell AmazonMQ to create more consumers? Can a single consumer be used to manage multiple concurrent lambda invocations?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Lambda doesn't autoscale with Amazon MQ as an event source. It has a fixed concurrency. For ActiveMQ it is 5, for Rabbit MQ it is 3. Note that these values may change without any notice.
Take this from [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QULMh9u3wVSTu9-wUBvneqnw/lambda-does-not-scale-for-amazon-mq-rabbit-mq-event-source)